# CRC32 calculation with CRC hash at the beginning of the message in C

Tags: c, reverse-engineering, crc32

I need to calculate CRC of the message and put it **at the beginning** of this message, so that the final CRC of the message with 'prepended' patch bytes equals 0. I was able to do this very easily with the help of few articles, but not for my specific parameters. The thing is that I have to use a given CRC32 algorithm which calculates the CRC of the memory block, but I don't have that 'reverse' algorithm that calculates those 4 patch bytes/'kind of CRC'. Parameters of the given CRC32 algorithm are:

- Polynomial: 0x04C11DB7
- Endianess: big-endian
- Initial value: 0xFFFFFFFF
- Reflected: false
- XOR out with: 0L
- Test stream: 0x0123, 0x4567, 0x89AB, 0xCDEF results in CRC = 0x612793C3

The code to calculate the CRC (half-byte, table-driven, I hope data type definitions are self-explanatory):

```
uint32 crc32tab(uint16* data, uint32 len, uint32 crc)
{
    uint8 nibble;
    int i;
    while(len--)
    {
        for(i = 3; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            nibble = (*data >> i*4) & 0x0F;
            crc = ((crc << 4) | nibble) ^ tab[crc >> 28];
        }
        data++;
    }

    return crc;
}
```

The table needed is (I thougth the short [16] table should contain every 16th element from the large [256] table, but this table contains actually **first** 16 elements, but that's how it was provided to me):

```
static const uint32 tab[16]=
{
    0x00000000, 0x04C11DB7, 0x09823B6E, 0x0D4326D9,
    0x130476DC, 0x17C56B6B, 0x1A864DB2, 0x1E475005,
    0x2608EDB8, 0x22C9F00F, 0x2F8AD6D6, 0x2B4BCB61,
    0x350C9B64, 0x31CD86D3, 0x3C8EA00A, 0x384FBDBD
};
```

I modified the code so it's not so long, but the functionality stays the same. The problem is that this forward CRC calculation looks more like backward/reverse CRC calc.
I've spent almost a week trying to find out the correct polynomial/algorithm/table combination, but with no luck. If it helps, I came up with bit-wise algorithm that corresponds to table-driven code above, although that was not so hard after all:

```
uint32 crc32(uint16* data, uint32 len, uint32 crc)
{
    uint32 i;
    while(len--)
    {
        for(i = 0; i < 16; i++)
        {
            // #define POLY 0x04C11DB7
            crc = (crc << 1) ^ (((crc ^ *data) & 0x80000000) ? POLY : 0);
        }
        crc ^= *data++;
    }

    return crc;
}
```

Here are expected results - first 2 16-bit words make the needed unknown CRC and the rest is the known data itself (by feeding these examples to provided algorithm, the result is 0).

```
{0x3288, 0xD244, 0xCDEF, 0x89AB, 0x4567, 0x0123}
{0xC704, 0xDD7B, 0x0000} - append as many zeros as you like, the result is the same
{0xCEBD, 0x1ADD, 0xFFFF}
{0x81AB, 0xB932, 0xFFFF, 0xFFFF}
{0x0857, 0x0465, 0x0000, 0x0123}
{0x1583, 0xD959, 0x0123}
   ^        ^
   |        |
   unknown bytes that I need to calculate
```

I think testing this on 0xFFFF or 0x0000 words is convenient because the direction of calculation and endianess is not important (I hope :D). So be careful to use other test bytes, because the direction of calculation is quite devious :D. Also you can see that by feeding only zeros to the algorithm (both forward and backward), the result is so-called residue (0xC704DD7B), that may be helpful.

So...I wrote at least 10 different functions (bite-wise, tables, combination of polynomials etc.) trying to solve this, but with no luck. I give you here the function in which I put my hopes into. It's 'reversed' algorithm of the table-driven one above, with different table of course. The problem is that the only correct CRC I get from that is with all 0s message and that's not so unexpected. Also I have written the reversed implementation of the bit-wise algorithm (reversed shifts, etc.), but that one returns only the first byte correctly.
Here is the table-driven one, pointer to *data* should point to the last element of the message and *crc* input should be the requested crc (0s for the whole message or you can maybe take another approach - that the last 4 bytes of message are the CRC you are looking for: [Calculating CRC initial value instead of appending the CRC to payload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28714815/calculating-crc-initial-value-instead-of-appending-the-crc-to-payload)) :

```
uint32 crc32tabrev(uint16* data, uint32 len, uint32 crc)
{
    uint8 nibble;
    int i;
    while(len--)
    {
        for(i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            nibble = (*data >> i*4) & 0x0F;
            crc = (crc >> 4) ^ revtab[((crc ^ nibble) & 0x0F)];
        }
        data--;
     }

     return reverse(crc); //reverse() flips all bits around center (MSB <-> LSB ...) 
}
```

The table, which I hope is 'the chosen one':

```
static const uint32 revtab[16]=
{
    0x00000000, 0x1DB71064, 0x3B6E20C8, 0x26D930AC,
    0x76DC4190, 0x6B6B51F4, 0x4DB26158, 0x5005713C,
    0xEDB88320, 0xF00F9344, 0xD6D6A3E8, 0xCB61B38C,
    0x9B64C2B0, 0x86D3D2D4, 0xA00AE278, 0xBDBDF21C
};
```

As you can see, this algorithm has some perks which make me run in circles and I think I'm maybe on the right track, but I'm missing something. I hope an extra pair of eyes will see what I can not. I'm sorry for the long post (no potato :D), but I think all of that explanation was neccessary. Thank you in advance for insight or advice.

Comment: Your CRC calculations are totally messed up.  The table entry is selected using the exclusive-or of the bits from the message and the high bits of the CRC.  For your bit-wise CRC routine, your decision on whether or not to exclusive-or with `POLY` is independent of the `^ *data`, so that doesn't even need to be there!  The correct way is to shift the data up to the top of the CRC and then decide on the high bit.  You are not calculating the CRC you specified, which by the way is the MPEG2 CRC-32.

Comment: Well you are right those calculations of CRC are incorrect, but I can't change that, because that original CRC calculation and table was given to me together with algorithm parameters and I just needed to find those 4 patch bytes. If the offical CRC-32/MPEG-2 algorithm passes that test stream in my question, then I guess I'm the one who is wrong here, but I think who made that algorithm (the one given to me) didn't follow specifications as he should. But that XOR with *data was my mistake, true...the original was (... & 1), so I just changed 1 to 0x80000000 thinking it would help :D

Comment: You should post the original CRC calculation and table with _no changes whatsoever_.  Maybe the original is ok.

Comment: well the table is the same and calculation also, it was divided into 3 functions, so I just put it all together..but as I wrote, that short table should contain every 16th element of the large table (at least that's what I read), but this table contains firts 16 elements of the large table, there's the problem I think

Comment: So you changed it.  You should post the original _with no changes_.

Comment: The problem is not in the table.  The table is correct.

Comment: You should not call your checksum a CRC, since what you're calculating is not a CRC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, few hours after my question, someone whose name I don't remember posted an answer to my question which turned out to be correct. Somehow this answer got completely deleted, I don't know why or who did it, but I'd like to thank to this person and in the case you will see this, please post your answer again and I'll delete this one. But for other users, here's his answer that worked for me, thank you again, mysterious one (unfortunately, I can't replicate his notes and suggestions well enough, just the code itself):

Edit: The original answer came from user [samgak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/696391/samgak), so this stays here until he'll post his answer.

The reverse CRC algorithm:

```
uint32 revcrc32(uint16* data, uint32 len, uint32 crc)
{
     uint32 i;
     data += len - 1;

     while(len--)
     {
         crc ^= *data--;
         for(i = 0; i < 16; i++)
         {
             uint32 crc1 = ((crc ^ POLY) >> 1) | 0x80000000;
             uint32 crc2 = crc >> 1;
             if(((crc1 << 1) ^ (((crc1 ^ *data) & 0x80000000) ? POLY : 0)) == crc)
                 crc = crc1;
             else if(((crc2 << 1) ^ (((crc2 ^ *data) & 0x80000000) ? POLY : 0)) == crc)
                 crc = crc2;
         }
     }
     return crc;
}
```

Find patch bytes:

```
#define CRC_OF_ZERO 0xb7647d
void bruteforcecrc32(uint32 targetcrc)
{
    // compute prefixes:
    uint16 j;
    for(j = 0; j <= 0xffff; j++)
    {
        uint32 crc = revcrc32(&j, 1, targetcrc);
        if((crc >> 16) == (CRC_OF_ZERO >> 16))
        {
           printf("prefixes: %04lX %04lX\n", (crc ^ CRC_OF_ZERO) & 0xffff, (uint32)j);
           return;
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
uint16 test[] = {0x0123, 0x4567, 0x89AB, 0xCDEF};  // prefix should be 0x0CD8236A

bruteforcecrc32(revcrc32(test, 4, 0L));
```

Comment: It was "samgak".  The answer was deleted by the owner, samgak.

Comment: That was [Samgak](http://stackoverflow.com/users/696391/samgak) – apparently he deleted his answer because your function "is not the correct implementation of CRC32", even though his solution works (basically, he's agreeing with Mark Adler). So you may want to take a second look at it, just to make sure.

Comment: thanks for the name, I hope he will post it again. Also I know it's not the correct/usual implementation, that's why I wrote here after a week of trying to do it the usual way. Someone implemented this kind of CRC32 and I can't do much about it, everything that was given to me was given to you in the first paragraph of my question. thank you again

Comment: You already said that is is not in fact what you were given.  You modified what you were given to "just put it all together".

Comment: maybe, but the result is the same, I basically made i++ from i = i + 1, but I don't want to argue, I'm just saying these modifications I did were for the sake of shortening the code, also it's better readable for those who know how crc works....if I offended you or the community somehow, I'm sorry for that

Comment: You are not offending, but we can't help you if you don't show what was originally provided.  You are assuming that you did not mess something up when you were "shortening the code" so that it is "better readable".  However we already have an example where "that XOR with *data was my mistake, true", "thinking it would help".

Comment: you are right again, but I was assuming that I did not mess something up only because the returned crc was still the same and it's maybe not very clever to do it this way, but we are takling about crc, where every little mistake is punishable by bad result, but I'm sure you have also reasonable response to that, so we shouldn't continue with this offtopic comments....thank you again for your time, because I've learnt more in this single thread than others as it addressed my exact problem

Answer (score 7):

I will answer for your CRC specification, that of a [CRC-32/MPEG-2](http://reveng.sourceforge.net/crc-catalogue/all.htm#crc.cat.crc-32-mpeg-2).  I will have to ignore your attempts at calculating that CRC, since they are incorrect.

Anyway, to answer your question, I happen to have written a program that solves this problem.  It is called [`spoof.c`](https://github.com/madler/spoof).  It very rapidly computes what bits to change in a message to get a desired CRC.  It does this in order log(n) time, where n is the length of the message.  Here is an example:

Let's take the nine-byte message `123456789` (those digits represented in ASCII).  We will prepend it with four zero bytes, which we will change to get the desired CRC at the end.  The message in hex is then: `00 00 00 00 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39`.  Now we compute the CRC-32/MPEG-2 for that message.  We get `373c5870`.

Now we run `spoof` with this input, which is the CRC length in bits, the fact that it is not reflected, the polynomial, the CRC we just computed, the length of the message in bytes, and all 32 bit locations in the first four bytes (which is what we are allowing `spoof` to change):

```
32 0 04C11DB7
373c5870 13
0 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 
1 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
2 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
3 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
```

It gives this output with what bits in those first four bytes to set:

```
invert these bits in the sequence:
offset bit
     0 1
     0 2
     0 4
     0 5
     0 6
     1 0
     1 2
     1 5
     1 7
     2 0
     2 2
     2 5
     2 6
     2 7
     3 0
     3 1
     3 2
     3 4
     3 5
     3 7
```

We then set the first four bytes to: `76 a5 e5 b7`.  We then test by computing the CRC-32/MPEG-2 of the message `76 a5 e5 b7 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39` and we get `00000000`, the desired result.

You can adapt `spoof.c` to your application.

Here is an example that correctly computes the CRC-32/MPEG-2 on a stream of bytes using a bit-wise algorithm:

```
uint32_t crc32m(uint32_t crc, const unsigned char *buf, size_t len)
{
    int k;

    while (len--) {
        crc ^= (uint32_t)(*buf++) << 24;
        for (k = 0; k < 8; k++)
            crc = crc & 0x80000000 ? (crc << 1) ^ 0x04c11db7 : crc << 1;
    }
    return crc;
}
```

and with a nybble-wise algorithm using the table in the question (which is correct):

```
uint32_t crc_table[] = {
    0x00000000, 0x04C11DB7, 0x09823B6E, 0x0D4326D9,
    0x130476DC, 0x17C56B6B, 0x1A864DB2, 0x1E475005,
    0x2608EDB8, 0x22C9F00F, 0x2F8AD6D6, 0x2B4BCB61,
    0x350C9B64, 0x31CD86D3, 0x3C8EA00A, 0x384FBDBD
};

uint32_t crc32m_nyb(uint32_t crc, const unsigned char *buf, size_t len)
{
    while (len--) {
        crc ^= (uint32_t)(*buf++) << 24;
        crc = (crc << 4) ^ crc_table[crc >> 28];
        crc = (crc << 4) ^ crc_table[crc >> 28];
    }
    return crc;
}
```

In both cases, the initial CRC must be `0xffffffff`.

Comment: thank you for your answer, I'm sure someone will make a good use of it, but in my case, the CRC algorithm that calculates the CRC is kind of special and it doesn't follow specifications (CRC-32/MPEG-2) which it says it does (at least I think so), the answer above solved it with that brute force, but that answer was deleted, I don't know why and also I don't know who posted it in the first place. But thank you again for your answer, it'll surely help someone with my problem and CRC generator which follows specifications :D :)

Answer (score 1):

Alternate approach. Assumes xorout = 0, if not, then after calculating the normal crc, then crc ^= xorout to remove it. The method here multiplies the normal crc by (1/2)%(crc polynomial) raised to (message size in bits) power % (crc polynomial) equivalent to cycling it backwards. If the message size is fixed, then the mapping is fixed and time complexity is O(1). Otherwise, it's O(log(n)).

This example code uses Visual Studio and an intrinsic for carryless multiply (PCLMULQDQ), which uses XMM (128 bit) registers. Visual Studio uses __m128i type to represent integer XMM values.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <intrin.h>

typedef unsigned char       uint8_t;
typedef unsigned int       uint32_t;
typedef unsigned long long uint64_t;

#define POLY  (0x104c11db7ull)
#define POLYM ( 0x04c11db7u)

static uint32_t crctbl[256];

static __m128i poly;                    /* poly */
static __m128i invpoly;                 /* 2^64 / POLY */

void GenMPoly(void)                     /* generate __m128i poly info */
{
uint64_t N = 0x100000000ull;
uint64_t Q = 0;
    for(size_t i = 0; i < 33; i++){
        Q <<= 1;
        if(N&0x100000000ull){
            Q |= 1;
            N ^= POLY;
        }
        N <<= 1;
    }
    poly.m128i_u64[0] = POLY;
    invpoly.m128i_u64[0] = Q;
}

void GenTbl(void)                       /* generate crc table */
{
uint32_t crc;
uint32_t c;
uint32_t i;
    for(c = 0; c < 0x100; c++){
        crc = c<<24;
        for(i = 0; i < 8; i++)
            /* assumes twos complement */
            crc = (crc<<1)^((0-(crc>>31))&POLYM);
        crctbl[c] = crc;
    }
}

uint32_t GenCrc(uint8_t * bfr, size_t size) /* generate crc */
{
uint32_t crc = 0xffffffffu;
    while(size--)
        crc = (crc<<8)^crctbl[(crc>>24)^*bfr++];
    return(crc);
}

/* carryless multiply modulo poly */
uint32_t MpyModPoly(uint32_t a, uint32_t b) /* (a*b)%poly */
{
__m128i ma, mb, mp, mt;
    ma.m128i_u64[0] = a;
    mb.m128i_u64[0] = b;
    mp = _mm_clmulepi64_si128(ma, mb, 0x00);      /* p[0] = a*b */
    mt = _mm_clmulepi64_si128(mp, invpoly, 0x00); /* t[1] = (p[0]*((2^64)/POLY))>>64 */
    mt = _mm_clmulepi64_si128(mt, poly, 0x01);    /* t[0] = t[1]*POLY */
    return mp.m128i_u32[0] ^ mt.m128i_u32[0];     /* ret =  p[0] ^ t[0] */
}

/* exponentiate by repeated squaring modulo poly */
uint32_t PowModPoly(uint32_t a, uint32_t b)     /* pow(a,b)%poly */
{
uint32_t prd = 0x1u;                    /* current product */
uint32_t sqr = a;                       /* current square */
    while(b){
        if(b&1)
            prd = MpyModPoly(prd, sqr);
        sqr = MpyModPoly(sqr, sqr);
        b >>= 1;
    }
    return prd;
}

int main()
{
uint32_t inv;                               /* 1/2 % poly, constant */
uint32_t fix;                               /* fix value, constant if msg size fixed */
uint32_t crc;                               /* crc at end of msg */
uint32_t pre;                               /* prefix for msg */
uint8_t msg[13] = {0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x31,0x32,0x33,0x34,0x35,0x36,0x37,0x38,0x39};

    GenMPoly();                             /* generate __m128i polys */
    GenTbl();                               /* generate crc table */
    inv = PowModPoly(2, 0xfffffffeu);       /* inv = 2^(2^32-2) % Poly = 1/2 % poly */
    fix = PowModPoly(inv, 8*sizeof(msg));   /* fix value */
    crc = GenCrc(msg, sizeof(msg));         /* calculate normal crc */
    pre = MpyModPoly(fix, crc);             /* convert to prefix */
    printf("crc = %08x pre = %08x ", crc, pre);
    msg[0] = (uint8_t)(pre>>24);            /* store prefix in msg */
    msg[1] = (uint8_t)(pre>>16);
    msg[2] = (uint8_t)(pre>> 8);
    msg[3] = (uint8_t)(pre>> 0);
    crc = GenCrc(msg, sizeof(msg));         /* check result */
    if(crc == 0)
        printf("passed\n");
    else
        printf("failed\n");
    return 0;
}
```